Upload multiple images flutter
I have these body in postman,where the image params look like this, and it support base64.

And here my code:
Future createComment( ..., List<dynamic>? urlImage) async {
  
  
    List<String> imgList = [];

    if (urlImage!.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var i in urlImage) {
          List<int> imageBytes = File(i).readAsBytesSync();
          String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
          imgList.add("data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Image);
        }
      }
    }

    var headers = {
     ...
    };

    var url = xxx ;

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: {
          ...
      for (var i in imgList) 'canvas_images[]': i,
    });
    var res = json.decode(response.body);
 
    return res;
  }

I tried using postman, I can get multiple images on the server side. But if I run using code, I only get the last image. What's wrong here?

flutter didn't allow to have duplicate map key or it will be override that why you only get last image

Try below code...
      var headers = {
        ...
      };
    
      var url = 'xxx';
    
      var body = {
       // other params
      };
    
      if (imgList.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
          body['canvas_images[$i]'] = imgList[i];
        }
      }
    
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body);
      var res = json.decode(response.body);
    


put the if statement outside var body?

Yes, if imgList in not empty then it's execute next line of for loop and append body.

It works. Thanks
